# How can i applay WPF ListView ItemContainerStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

i use datatemplate selector and itemcontainerstyle.
mouseover is not active

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="listViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
         <DataTemplate x:Key="boolTemplate" DataType="{x:Type Models:ParameterListBoxItem}">
            <Grid>
                <CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
                    </CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                </CheckBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="numTemplate" DataType="{x:Type Models:ParameterListBoxItem}">
            <Grid>
                <TextBox/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <Models:TestTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector" 
                                    BooleanDataTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=boolTemplate}"
                                    NumDataTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=numTemplate}"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
<ListView x:Name="lb" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" 
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource listViewStyle}"
          Background="#FF555555" Foreground="White" FontSize="20"/>
</Grid>
```

ParameterListBoxItem has an object type property.
That property name is TestValue.

This TestValue is assigned either int or bool.
Depending on the assigned type, the templateselector changes the datatemplate.
When I run the action, the CheckBox and TextBox appear properly.

I thought that when I hover the mouse over the item, mouseover would be executed by ItemContainerStyle and the background color would change to red.

But Windows default background appear.
Why ItemContainerStyle don't working??

Comment: you can try specific Template of ListViewItem.Your template may contains a GridViewRowPresenter within a Border. you can change the Border Background in your triggers. refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/listview-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: You would have to override the ControlTemplate of the ListViewItem. This is necessary because the original template differentiates between background color and highlight color. Changing the background brush does not affect the highlight brush. You want to change the highlight brush but there is no such property that your trigger could manipulate. Hence you must move your trigger into the ControlTemplate.